# Gradle- Multi-project with outside projects?

Tags: java, gradle

Is it not possible in a Gradle multi-project setup to use external dependencies outside the main project folder?

Like in the `settings.gradle` file, can I not have something like

`include 'C:\some\path\to\dependent\project\ChildA','ChildB'`

or do I have to *always* include the dependent projects in the parent project folder?

Comment: Yes you can: `include ":projectA", ":projectB" but they must be modules in your current project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the following filesystem hierarchy:

```
|
 \ workspace
     |
      \
       MyProject
     |
      \
       DependencyA
```

Add the following into your `settings.gradle` in `MyProject`:

```
include '..:DependencyA'
```

and inside your inner `build.gradle` of `MyProject`

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':..:DependencyA')
}
```

Repeat for as many projects as you have that depend on `DependencyA`.

Comment: Ah I see. How Linux-y. I will definitely need to test this tonight.

Comment: Won't using `..:DependencyA` make gradle think that there is a subproject `..` and that project has a subproject `DependencyA`? (try running `gradle -q projects` in MyProject) I would prefer `include ':DependencyA'  project(':DependencyA').projectDir = file('../DependencyA')`

Comment: I'm not sure that `..` would be inferred as a project, and rather this is a special case handled by gradle (it does after all look up into the parent directory)

Comment: `Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.`