# Sharing a library project between two Android Studio projects

Tags: android, android-studio, module

I'm in the process of migrating over from Eclipse and I'm certainly having some growing pains.

Eclipse was very straightforward with Android Library projects. Create a project, mark it as an Android Library, and then reference it from non-library Android projects in the same workspace. When code changes in the library project, nothing needed to be changed in the non-library projects.

Android Studio does not seem to be so simple. I've worked my way through the tutorials and I have gotten to the point where I can import my library project as a module, and add it as a dependency to my app module.

But the huge issue here is that it copies my entire library module into the non-library project as a sub-folder. Now, when I make changes to my library project, they are not reflected in my non-library projects unless I manually remove the module, delete the sub-folder, and re-add the library module.

I hope this is not how this was intended. Maybe I'm doing something wrong? Can someone give me some pointers?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I answered a similar question a week ago. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29884255/276949

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I included my library project in my settings.grade, but when I try to add compile project(':..:LibProject') to my build.gradle, I get the error "Configuration with name 'default' not found"

Comment: Make sure your library project has a `build.gradle` file.

Comment: It does... buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

Comment: Solved. I had to add the module name (include '..:LibProject:app') (compile project(':..:LibProject:app'))